# Formation of Cosmic Microwave Background

Tags: cosmology, big-bang-theory, cosmic-microwave-background

It is said that the cosmic microwave radiation (CMB) was formed when the universe was 379,000 years old. How is this calculated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We observe the temperature of the CMB as a ~2.7 K blackbody, but that's the redshifted version we observe. The CMB is also know as the "surface of last scattering" at the point of  [recombination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recombination_(cosmology)) when nuclei and electrons combined to form neutral atoms the universe went from opaque to transparent.

This happens at a [temperature](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept02/Kinney/Kinney3.html) of ~3000 K. From this we can estimate the redshift (z~1100) of the CMB which corresponds to an age given our cosmology.